# Ajax XMLHttpRequest Response very slow

Tags: php, ajax

I am currently working on php project in which i use ajax xml to pass the data and get the data.on my development server its working very well i got ajax respose quickly but on the live server ajax respose are coming very very slow.

I have checked it in firefox firebug net ,it sometime displyed response aborted. i can not figure out what is the issue on live server?

is there an issue regarding server?

I really appreciate any help I can get!

Thanx In Advace..

Comment: Put your code here so that we can debug.

Comment: This could be an overloaded server, slow network, ...

Comment: Do you have the same delay when accessing the called URL directly (not via AJAX)? Describe the configuration of your dev machine.

Comment: is there coding issue ? because it works very well on development server. i got response very fast on it ?

Answer (score 1):

use json as JSON is lighter than XML .php has good [json encoding functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). As your request getting aborted this seems tobe maximum execution time issue. increase the execution time of php by adding ini_set('max_execution_time', 300) , now script execution time is 300 seconds.
if problem still persists you can use cacheing or cdn  techniques to speed up your response time.

Here is a nice article on various cacheing techniques : http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2008/02/27/php-performance-series-caching-techniques/